# rail 3 omniauth google account login Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am using omniauth to get login using google account. For local its working, when I moved in production i am getting permission denided error.

here is the code in omniauth.rb

```
require 'openid/store/filesystem'

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do    
    provider :open_id, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp')    
end
```

production enviroment i am getting this error

> Errno::EACCES
>
> Permission denied -
>   /tmp/temp/tmp20110502-27770-1tje7xp.lock
>
> Rails.root:
>   /home/deployer/releases/20110502083952

I am using passenger and nginx in production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are your deploying your application?

Try:

```
provider :open_id, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('./tmp')
```

Hope this helps.